# Add signature field on rotated document

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I am trying to add signature field on rotated document but I want to have no rotation applied on signature field and it should be added on rotated page with 0 rotation.

I have tried the following method but it does not work for me.

```
page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);
```

Could anyone provide solution of this issue?

[image: screen shots]

**Signature appearance code snippet:**

```
    PdfFormXObject layer2Object = _pdfSignatureAppearance.GetLayer2();

    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(layer2Object, _pdfSigner.GetDocument());
    PdfPage page = _pdfSigner.GetDocument().GetPage(signingRequest.Page <= 0 ? 
    signingRequest.PageNumber : signingRequest.Page);
    page = page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(false);
    int pageRotation = page.GetRotation();
    Canvas appearanceCanvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, _pdfSigner.GetDocument(), 
    layer2Object.GetBBox().ToRectangle());

    ImageData signatureImageData = 
    ImageDataFactory.Create(signingRequest.SignatureImage);
    Image signatureImage = new Image(signatureImageData);
    signatureImageData.SetRotation(0f);
    ImageData logoImageData = 
    ImageDataFactory.Create(Convert.FromBase64String(signingRequest.Logo));
    Image logoImage = new Image(logoImageData);
 logoImageData.SetRotation(0f);

KeyValuePair<string, SignatureAppearanceField> handSignatureKey = appearanceFieldSettings.Where(o => o.Key == SignatureAppearanceAttributes.HAND_SIGNATURE.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
 appearanceAttributes = new Paragraph().SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)).SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)).SetMargin(0.01f).SetStrokeWidth(0.1f);
 handSignatureImage.SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
 handSignatureImage = handSignatureImage.SetAutoScale(true);
 handSignatureImage.SetMarginLeft((handSignatureKey.Value.X / aspectRatio) + 10);
 if (appearanceFieldSettings.ContainsKey("COMPANY_LOGO"))
 {
 if (fieldSettings.Key == SignatureAppearanceAttributes.COMPANY_LOGO.ToString())
 {
 IList<Image> images = new List<Image>();
 KeyValuePair<string, SignatureAppearanceField> companySignatureKey = appearanceFieldSettings.Where(o => o.Key == SignatureAppearanceAttributes.COMPANY_LOGO.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
 companyLogoImage.SetAutoScale(true);
 companyLogoImage.SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
 companyLogoImage.SetMarginLeft((companySignatureKey.Value.Width / aspectRatio) - 20);
 images.Add(handSignatureImage);
 images.Add(companyLogoImage);
 appearanceAttributes.AddAll(images);
if (pageRotation > 0)
 {
 handSignatureImage.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 companyLogoImage.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 appearanceAttributes.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 }
appearanceCanvas.Add(appearanceAttributes);
 }
 }
 else
 {
 if (pageRotation > 0)
 {
 handSignatureImage.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 appearanceAttributes.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 }
 appearanceAttributes.Add(handSignatureImage);
 appearanceCanvas.Add(appearanceAttributes);
 }
```

**Setting signed by and signing reason;**

```
    KeyValuePair<string, SignatureAppearanceField> signingReasonKey = appearanceFieldSettings.Where(o => o.Key == SignatureAppearanceAttributes.SIGNING_REASON.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
 string reason = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(signingRequest.WitnessReason) ? signingRequest.WitnessReason : signingRequest.SigningReason;
 if (reason.Length > 25)
 reason = reason.Substring(0, 25) + " ...";
 Text signingReasonText = null;
 appearanceAttributes = new Paragraph().SetFontSize(signingReasonKey.Value.Font.FontSize / aspectRatio).SetMargin(0.01f).SetStrokeWidth(0.1f);
 if (signingReasonKey.Value.ShowLabel)
 {
 signingReasonText = new Text(signingReasonKey.Value.LabelName + ": " + reason);
 }
 else
 {
 signingReasonText = new Text(reason);
 }
if (pageRotation > 0)
 {
 appearanceAttributes.SetRotationAngle((Math.PI / 180) * pageRotation);
 }
appearanceAttributes.Add(signingReasonText);
 appearanceCanvas.Add(appearanceAttributes);
```

[image]

Comment: `SetIgnorePageRotationForContent` allows to ignore page rotation for **content** but signature visualizations are not **content** but **annotations**. How about rotating the signature visualization to counter the observed effect?

Comment: @mkl

I have attached the issued doc here:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihVIJBafez7kcmQ3?e=u2GBOy

I am creating custom signature appearance using Image and Paragraph and adding them to layout.Canvas.
I have tried the solution with 180 and 270 degree rotated documents also but text is not adjusted in those rotations too.
Could you please guide me in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: *"but text is not adjusted in those rotations"* - what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @mkl
Please see the following image for further clearance of the issue
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihYM0vmgBl-vy81p?e=hfF4Ro

Comment: In that image you show the *faulty appearance on rotated document* and *the normal appearance rendered on non-rotated document* but not the *desired appearance on rotated document*. It would be great if you could sketch that, too, in particular in respect to the rotation of it and its content. (By the way, I just added your image to your question.)

Comment: @mkl
The signature appearance on rotated document should also be displayed same as the one on non-rotated document. As I mentioned before that I want no rotation effect on signature appearance contents and the signature appearance content should be displayed same as the one on non-rotated document.
Please note the content of signature appearance on both images are same.

Regards

Comment: Just to be clear, the rectangle in the rotated document screen shot is at the correct place, merely the content should be as in the rectangle in the non-rotated screen shot?

Comment: @mkl
Yes the rectangle in the rotated document is at the correct place

Comment: @MuddassirAwan hi, can you attach your code?

Comment: @AlexeySubach
I am afraid I could not be able to add the complete code however I have added a code snippet of adding image and text to the appearance.

Comment: @mkl
Could you guide me by take a look into the code snippet added.

Comment: It's good that you added your code because I just tried signing your prepared signature field using the appearances built by iText itself and could not reproduce your issue. According to your code, though, you construct the appearance yourself which explains the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I used the revision from your example file which has two empty signature fields and which is not yet signed. Furthermore, I used a re-built version of your signature image.*

#### Using iText default appearances

As a first check I applied regular iText signing code in which iText itself fills the appearance of the signature:

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDF_SOURCE))
{
    PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, File.Create(PDF_DEST), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
    ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(IMAGE_SOURCE);

    pdfSigner.SetFieldName("SH_SIGNATURE_417868");

    PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
    sigAppearance.SetContact("ContactInfo");
    sigAppearance.SetLocation("Location");
    sigAppearance.SetReason("SigningReason");
    sigAppearance.SetLayer2Text("Muddassir Awan");
    sigAppearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
    sigAppearance.SetRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
    sigAppearance.SetSignatureCreator("Muddassir Awan");

    int estimatedSize = 12000;
    pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached), estimatedSize);
}
```

The result:

[image: Screen shot]

Thus, this works.

Apparently, though, you want the data to be arranged differently, so we have to try to essentially do the same as the appearance generation code of iText merely with a different arrangement of the components.

#### Using custom appearances

As the iText code works (as seen above) and your code references a number of variables I don't have here, I wrote this from scratch, borrowing code from iText (`PdfSignatureAppearance.GetAppearance()` to be more precise), aiming at creating an appearance somewhat similar to your screenshot for a non-rotated document:

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDF_SOURCE))
{
    PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, File.Create(PDF_DEST), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());

    ImageData signatureImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(IMAGE_SOURCE);
    Image signatureImage = new Image(signatureImageData);

    pdfSigner.SetFieldName("SH_SIGNATURE_417868");

    PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
    sigAppearance.SetContact("ContactInfo");
    sigAppearance.SetLocation("Location");
    sigAppearance.SetReason("SigningReason");
    sigAppearance.SetSignatureCreator("Muddassir Awan");

    PdfPage page = pdfSigner.GetDocument().GetPage(sigAppearance.GetPageNumber());
    int rotation = page.GetRotation();

    PdfFormXObject layer2Object = sigAppearance.GetLayer2();
    Rectangle rect = layer2Object.GetBBox().ToRectangle();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(layer2Object, pdfSigner.GetDocument());

    if (rotation == 90)
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(0, 1, -1, 0, rect.GetWidth(), 0);
    else if (rotation == 180)
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, rect.GetWidth(), rect.GetHeight());
    else if (rotation == 270)
        pdfCanvas.ConcatMatrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, rect.GetHeight());

    Rectangle rotatedRect = 0 == (rotation / 90) % 2 ? new Rectangle(rect.GetWidth(), rect.GetHeight()) : new Rectangle(rect.GetHeight(), rect.GetWidth());
    Canvas appearanceCanvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfSigner.GetDocument(), rotatedRect);

    Paragraph text = new Paragraph();
    text.SetFontSize(7).Add("Signed by: Muddassir Awan\nReason: I approve this document\nSigned at: 2020-02-20 16:55:20 +05:00");
    appearanceCanvas.Add(text);

    signatureImage.ScaleToFit(rotatedRect.GetWidth(), 40);
    appearanceCanvas.Add(signatureImage);

    int estimatedSize = 12000;
    pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached), estimatedSize);
}
```

The result:

[image: screen shot]

This is approximately what you want, except for the position fine tuning.

So one merely has to apply a rotation transformation to the `PdfCanvas` counteracting the page rotation and then select the `Canvas` rectangle according to that rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will wait for your response on USING CUSTOM SIGNATURE part.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the solution. It worked like a charm :).
There is one thing I am getting issue about that the final appearance on 270 and 90 degree rotated documents feels like zoomed out. I tried to fix the issue by changing the width and height values but the issue is not resolved.
For reference I have attached an image in the question.
Could you please guide me in this scenario.
Regards

Comment: I'll look into that next week.

Comment: I had a look at your new screen shots. I don't understand what you mean by *"feels like zoomed out"* on them. Can you explain? Probably by showing a sketch of what you would expect instead on those screen shots?

Comment: I menat by "feels like zoomed out" that the signature appearance rendered as per desired results after applying the solution provided by you but the signature appearance content is much smaller than the signature field size and as shown in the image I have attached.
The black border is the size of signature field and If you see the signature appearance content, it is much smaller than the field size rather to be fit according to the field size.
Regards

Comment: Ah. Well, in the example above I only concentrated on your issue, the rotation, but concerning the exact design I used non-optimized values, in particular the font size and the scale-to-fit height can be increased a bit. And if you used signature image with less empty space at top and bottom, it might fit even better.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to fit the signature appearance according to field size. I have done it on all rotations except 270 deg rotated document. I have tried to adjust the signature appearance but the LEFT of the canvas not been adjusted to the signature field left.
Could you please guide me for this specific scenario as I am unable to understand the "CONCATMATRIX" parameters.
Also the image is also not been rendered in this specific scenario.
Regards

Comment: Please share the PDF with the 270° rotated field. (I would prefer using your file to creating one myself because there are certain variants how this can be done, and I'd prefer working on the same variant as you.)

Comment: You can find the document on the following urls:
Signed:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihfsMr_AH82IX8tt?e=vyyR5T


Unsigned:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihhqJA0qJdRMGQyu?e=URMXsr

Comment: Your sample signed PDF here looks fine, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILA6p.png), not so small and shifted as in your screen shot. Thus, apparently you did something different here compared to what you did when generating that screen shot.

Comment: Ok I will check it at my end.
Could you please also guide me that why my image that is the text "muddassir awan" shown at bottom left is rendered small. As I must need to SetAutoScale value. otherwise it is not rendered in signature appearance. Sorry to bother but I am stuck at this

Comment: Have you cropped the massive empty frame around your your signature from the image?

Comment: No, I have jst added the appearance attributes in the appearance frame including image and text. Text could be resized bu setting font size but the image is only displayed when SetAutoScale is set to TRUE.

Comment: If you didn't crop the image, it moist likely simply doesn't fit without scaling. Thus, crop it or scale it.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try to scale it.
One last thing about the appearance rendering that Can I strict the text to be one liner if the text is large. Like in above appearance, if the reason or signed by text is large then it becomes 2 liner which I do not required. I want that text to be one liner.
Regards

Comment: Do you want that one line cut off? Or do you want the text in that line printed smaller or thinner?

Comment: I want that text to be printed smaller or thinner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208894/discussion-between-muddassir-awan-and-mkl).