# Siganture is not rendered on some specific documents

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I am facing an issue regarding signing using iText7. On some specific documents, the signature process completed successfully and signature is valid in Adobe, but the signature appearance is not visible and the signature is not Invisible.
For reference find the attached document below:

https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihngL6ZfyqzsJogy?e=r0vL91

My add signature code snippet is as following:

```
PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);

PDFSignaturePosition SigPosition = field.Position;

PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(SigPosition.Pages[i]);

if (page == null)
{
    page = pdfDocument.GetPage(SigPosition.PageNumber);
}

int rotation = page.GetRotation();
iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rect;
if (rotation > 0 && SigPosition.Position == PDFSignaturePosition.DefaultSignaturePosition.Custom)
{
    page = page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(false);
    rect = GetSignaturePositionAccordingToRotation(SigPosition.Rect, page.GetCropBox(), rotation);
}
else
{
    rect = GetSignaturePositionRect(SigPosition.Position, SigPosition.Rect, page.GetCropBox());
}

PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDocument, rect);

sig.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.VISIBLE);

sig.Put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g"));

sig.SetFieldName(i == 0 ? field.Name : field.Name + " - " + SigPosition.Pages[i]);

sig.SetPage(SigPosition.Pages[i]);

pdfAcroForm.AddField(sig, page);

sig.MakeIndirect(pdfDocument);

pdfAcroForm.GetPdfObject().Get(PdfName.Fields).SetModified();
pdfAcroForm.GetPdfObject().SetModified();

pdfDocument.Close();
```

Code snippet for adding dimensions in layer2Object rect:

```
layer2Rect.SetHeight((float)Convert.ToInt32(signingRequest.CollaboratorMainTask.FieldHeight));
                layer2Rect.SetWidth((float)Convert.ToInt32(signingRequest.CollaboratorMainTask.FieldWidth));

                float[] rectUpdatedValues = new float[] { 0, 0, layer2Rect.GetWidth(), layer2Rect.GetHeight() };
                PdfArray pdfArray = new PdfArray(rectUpdatedValues);
                layer2Object.SetBBox(pdfArray);
```

Comment: Your shared document does not contain a signature applied by iText 7.

Comment: @mkl
I have updated the signed document on following link:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoihqpTfE51T2W6sC_

Please note I am setting the custom signature appearance attributes but the signature becomes INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

> but the signature appearance is not visible and the signature is not Invisible

The rectangles defining the dimensions and locations of the visualizations of both your signature and your document time stamp are [0 0 0 0], see their **Rect** entries:

[image: dump of signature and document time stamp fields of "Appearance rendering issue-Signed.pdf"]

I.e. they are rectangles with size 0×0 at the origin. Signatures with 0×0 sized visualizations are considered invisible.

If you want visible signatures, therefore, give their fields non-vanishing dimensions.

Comment: I have checked in my code, When getting layer2 BBox, it has 0 values in all fields. So I need to set up the layer2 Rect by my self?

Comment: Without knowing your current code and use case, how should I tell? In [your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60433311/1729265) you filled a previously existing empty signature field. There it was the job of the creator of those previously existing fields to correctly set up field dimensions. If you're still in that use case, tell the person who prepared those signature fields to provide proper dimensions. If your use case has changed and you sign completely new fields, you yourself must of course set them up completely.

Comment: I am still in the existing use case.
I add signature field to PDF and sign that signature field using custom signature appearance.
Moreover I have added add signature code in the question.

Comment: Apparently your `GetSignaturePositionRect` method returns an empty rectangle or none at all.

Comment: I have checked and the signature add code has no issues as Unsigned fields are present in the document. I have also added the width and height in the layer2 rectangle through the following code but issue still not resolved:
I have added the code in question.
Regards